# Setting UITextContentType.emailAddress on a UITextView is not working

Tags: ios, swift, autofill

I have a [UITextView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview) which is set with UIKeyboardType of .emailAddress
I want to auto-suggest the user's email address with the [UITextContentType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype) property

I do so like so:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                        myTextView.textContentType = UITextContentType.emailAddress
                    }
```

However this is not working and I see no email in the suggestion box of the textview.

I have also tried the same thing with a UITextField but no dice.
Is there something I am missing? I have done everything according to the docs. 
[image]

Comment: Simulator or real device? If real device, does feature work in other apps?

Comment: Real device. I have seen the feature work sometimes yes (mainly in safari i think). Is there a setting in my iphone that would allow me to check this?

Comment: Password-autofill is setting you might want to check. Although I'm not sure. I created quick example with UITextField. I set the ContentType property in Interface Builder and it worked fine. Try: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itsdeductible/id725029107?mt=8, and go to Create Account flow. See password entry. If it doesn't work there, then it's a system issue.

Comment: @Daniel - Actually your thoughts just lead my to realize that I need to set the email in my contact card in the contacts app. Only then can the autofill use it. I had originally assumed it got the email from iCloud or one of the other places I have set it. Feel free to write an answer and I will mark it correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have set your email address in your own Contact card in the Contacts app.

:)

Comment: Daniel I have verified my contact card is there but still I can't see any suggestions.. :(

Comment: What about a credit card, where does it have to be stored in order to be suggested?

Answer (score 1):

In case of email addresses you need to set your `keyboardType` to `emailAddress` also.
I thought prediction/autocomplete is broken on iOS 13 but you just need to specify the right type of keyboard. This is how I got names and addresses to work:

```
textField.autocorrectionType = .yes
textField.textContentType = .givenName
textField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad
```