# How to show full name as predictive text in ios?

Tags: swift, textfield, autofill

I want to show full name suggestion in full name textfield with object

```
self.txtFullName.textContentType = .givenName
self.txtFullName.autocorrectionType = .yes
```

but by above code I am getting only first name. Please let me know how I can get full name in suggestion.

Comment: You may give more context here : what is your txtFullName type ? Maybe you can give a more detail sample of your code, including how your variables are declared, where they are displayed (UIViewController I presume), etc

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

```
self.txtFullName.textContentType = .name
```

Referring to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/1649669-name) about `.name`

> A property that defines the content in a text input area as a name.

Setting this property causes the full name suggestion to appear above the keyboard. It works for both UITextField and UITextView.

It's worth mentioning [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202680/11022124) about email type. This also applies to other types, including `.name`.
Also, make sure you are not testing this functionality on the simulator, because it just may not work even if you log in to your Apple ID.

P.S. Maybe it's too late for the answer, but I have answered anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the content types available in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype) the type you are using `.givenName` refers only to the first name.

> The expectation that a text input area specifies a first name.

Since the documentation declares `.givenName` and `.familyName` separately we can assume that Apple prefer us to have separate fields for these, however you could try `.name` as it appears more generic but not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks for reply! but i am not getting full name by this.

Comment: Then perhaps it's not possible at the moment.